# Close all disconnected tabs in SuperPuTTY at once?

Tags: superputty

Is there any way to close all disconnected tabs in [SuperPuTTY](https://code.google.com/p/superputty/) at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to close all disconnected tabs in SuperPuTTY at once.